# He was walking through/ on / in the streets of the city?

Tags: prepositions

Which **preposition** is the correct to put in the following sentence? For me all of them looks equal and I don't really have a reason why to choose one and not the other.

> He was walking (**through/ on / in**) the streets of the city?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*To walk through the streets...* is a common expression; as is *to walk along the street/s*. They mean exactly what they say.

*To walk in the streets*... suggests that the walker is not using the pavement/sidewalk intended for pedestrians but walking in the roadway used by the traffic. One frequently comes across *children playing in the streets*.

To *walk on the streets* is not idiomatic, although the expression *on the streets* (without walk) is common, referring to life/events that take place on the streets.

To *live on the streets* means to be homeless.

*In the Streets* and *Blame it on the Streets* are among the many movie titles that include the word *Streets*.